# React Native Calling async function and use return in another async function

Tags: react-native, async-await, react-redux, redux-thunk, thunk

I'm working with React Native and I have to call 2 Redux thunks before mount (useEffect). The first one is to get the user location. The second one gives me a list of animals near that location.

This is the location Thunk (useLocation is a custom hook):

```
export const getLocation = () => async (dispatch) => {
  await useLocation()
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch(getLocationSuccess(res));
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err, "ERROR");
    });
};
```

This works perfectly.

This is the animals thunk:

```
export const getAnimals = (data) => async (dispatch) => {
  await api.animals
    .list(data)
    .then((res) => {
        dispatch(getLostsSuccess(res.data));
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    });
};
```

This is the Api helpers:

import axios from "axios";

```
const requestHelper = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://192.168.0.15:8000/api/",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});

const routes = {
  animals: {
    list: (data) =>
      requestHelper({
        data,
        method: "post",
        url: "animals/list/",
      }),
};

export default routes;
```

And this is the component (useEffect and async):

```
useEffect(() => {
    asyncEffect()

  }, []);

 const asyncEffect = async () => {
    const location = await getLocation();
    getAnimals({ location: location, status: 1 });
  };
```

The "location" is send as empty object in getAnimals thunk, but on state is loading just fine. How can I use getAnimals thunk after getLocation returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getLocation` redux-action is not a regular async function to await for ... it's a function that return a function...

So I'd suggest you get the list of animals when you successfully get location in `getLocation` redux action

```
export const getLocation = () => async (dispatch) => {
  await useLocation()
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch(getLocationSuccess(res));
      /**
       * call getAnimals here // <<--
       */
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err, "ERROR");
    });
};
```

- 

```
 const asyncEffect = async () => {
    const location = await getLocation();
    // getAnimals({ location: location, status: 1 });
  };
```

**If you want to call getAnimals once**

```
/** Executes only on app-mount */
useEffect(() => {
 getLocation();
}, []);


useEffect(() => {
  if (location) {
    // get animals here
    getAnimals({ location: location, status: 1 });
  }
}, [location]); // location is pulled from redux-store using mapStateToProps
```

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for your answer. I will use "useLocation()" in several ways and in several components. That's why I added it to redux store. So I don't want that every time I call "useLocation", getAnimals is called. Is there another way to call it separately?